# Not receiving emails from Django's AdminEmailHandler?

Tags: python, django, logging

I'm working on configuring the error notifications for a Django project. For redundancy, I'd like to use both Django's [`AdminEmailHandler`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler) as well as Airbrake (with [`pybrake`](https://github.com/airbrake/pybrake)).

The problem is that although I'm receiving Airbrake notifications, I'm not receiving the Django error emails, which should contain the full traceback.

The project has multiple settings which inherit from `settings/base.py`, which contains

```
ANYMAIL = {
    "MAILGUN_API_KEY": os.getenv('MAILGUN_API_KEY'),
    "MAILGUN_SENDER_DOMAIN": 'mg.startwithlucy.com',
}
EMAIL_BACKEND = "anymail.backends.mailgun.EmailBackend"

# Airbrake (pybrake) settings
AIRBRAKE = dict(
    project_id=os.getenv('AIRBRAKE_PROJECT_ID'),
    project_key=os.getenv('AIRBRAKE_PROJECT_KEY'),
    environment=os.getenv('AIRBRAKE_ENVIRONMENT', default='production'),
    root_directory=os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)))

# Auxiliary variable used in LOGGING
_LOGGER = {
    'handlers': ['airbrake', 'mail_admins'],
    'level': 'ERROR',
    'propagate': True,
}

# Airbrake logging integration (cf. https://github.com/airbrake/pybrake#django-integration)
# In our case, 'app' is replaced by three apps, 'lucy_web', 'api', and 'activation'.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'airbrake': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'pybrake.LoggingHandler',
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'include_html': True,
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'lucy_web': _LOGGER,
        'api': _LOGGER,
        'activation': _LOGGER,
    },
}
```

The settings which I'm currently trying, `settings/staging.py`, contain

```
import os
import anyconfig
from lucy.settings.base import *

DEBUG = False

# Set the Airbrake environment to 'staging'
AIRBRAKE.update(environment='staging')

ADDITIONAL_LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        # The 'django' logger is the catch-all logger for messages in the Django hierarchy
        # (cf. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/#django)
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.getenv('LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
        },
    },
}

# Add logging to the console to the default Airbrake logging
anyconfig.merge(self=LOGGING, other=ADDITIONAL_LOGGING)

ADMINS = [
    ('Kurt Peek', 'kurt@hicleo.com'),
]
```

I have a testing view which raises a `ZeroDivisionError`, and I see the error in the Airbrake dashboard:

[image]

However, I haven't received any email, even though there is an `EMAIL_BACKEND` configured which works. Anything I overlooked?

Comment: Try to add `'mail_admins'` into this your handler: `'handlers': ['console'],` in *staging.py* file.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by [Chiefir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8495108/chiefir), I had indeed forgotten to add the `'mail_admins'` handler to the `'django'` logger.

There was also another issue, however, with the [`SERVER_EMAIL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#server-email) setting. This was not specified and therefore defaulted to `root@localhost`, but Mailgun only allows you to send emails from validated domains.

After making these two changes, the emails to `ADMINS` are received correctly.

Comment: SERVER_EMAIL was the last bit I needed to get right.